# Is there a right way of adding comments to git aliases?

Tags: git, comments, aliases

Many git aliases have very short abbreviations/acronyms/TLAs and long, almost impenetrable, command lines.

Is there a 'correct' way of adding a trailing comment to an alias so that I can remember what it was for, or where I got it from?

Does it depend on whether it was created via the `git config --global alias.<shrt> 'cmd'`  command or by directly editing my `.gitconfig` file, and also if it is a shell `!` command etc.

It would be great if there was a 'one size fits all' method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config file has a comment syntax, use that.

The first two sentences of the `Syntax` section in `git help config`:

```
   The syntax is fairly flexible and permissive; whitespaces are mostly ignored.
   The # and ; characters begin comments to the end of line, blank lines are ignored.
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'd missed the latter part - I was generally thinking the values were 'all one long line, up to the EOL'. In fact the https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_syntax section also allows the line continuation ` \ ` for name (such as `alias = `) values, as well as using double quotes where the `;` and `#` are part of the alias. Also within the double quote, it says that if not used for continuation the backslash need to be escaped ` \\ `.  Fun.